# I am trying to write my Object into a Json File after converting it in JsonObject but it is not getting written

Tags: java, json, file

Here is my data (value in myRecords) :

```
[Record{Purpose='Medical ', ID='9215524400  ', UpdateTime='2020-10-14', Checkin='2020-10-14'},...]
```

Here is my code :

```
        private FileWriter file;
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(myRecords);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            file = new FileWriter("NewFile.json");
            file.write(String.valueOf(jsonObj));
          }
```

I am not getting any errors but nothing is getting written into the file.

Comment: Are you trying to write everything to one file? Or Is there supposed to be a separate file for each record?

Comment: hey varsha, the method u have implemented is completely wrong . I mean to say,   json file formate will be wrong or either change the file name(.txt) or change the question.

Comment: @RohanKumar, I am trying to write everything to one file, but only 1st record is getting added.. I am quite new to java, Could you please tell me what  I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should take a look at my answer, you are missing append flag for FileWriter

Comment: @Varsha: polite ping, were you able to resolve this issue? You can take a look at code I wrote to test your use case: https://github.com/r0haaaan/stackoverflow-code/blob/master/java-posts/src/main/java/in/rohaan/WritingJsonToFile.java

Comment: @RohanKumar , yes , Thanks. but it seems my json data is not coming properly (it is not a legal json array), so I need to process it

Comment: Have you tried writing the array directly: https://github.com/r0haaaan/stackoverflow-code/blob/master/java-posts/src/main/java/in/rohaan/WritingJsonToFile.java#L51 ? I think if you directly do `file2.write(jsonArr.toString());` It should be valid json

Comment: I did, I am getting casting exceptions in  Arrays.stream(myRecords).forEach(r -> jsonArr.put(r.toJSON()));

Answer (score 1):

I think this statement is not working as expected:

```java
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(myRecords);
```

You would need to define object to JSON conversion yourself. You can define a `toJSON()` method in your `Record` class:

```java
private static class Record {
    private String purpose, id, updateTime, checkIn;

    public Record(String purpose, String id, String updateTime, String checkIn) {
        this.purpose = purpose;
        this.id = id;
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
        this.checkIn = checkIn;
    }

    public JSONObject toJSON() {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("purpose", this.purpose);
        jo.put("id", this.id);
        jo.put("updateTime", this.id);
        jo.put("checkIn", this.id);

        return jo;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply stream over your `Record` array to call `toJSON()` for each object:

```java
Record[] myRecords = {
        new Record("Medical", "1", "2020-10-14", "2020-10-14"),
        new Record("Pharma", "2", "2020-10-14", "2020-10-14"),
        new Record("Security", "3", "2020-10-14", "2020-10-14"),
};

JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
Arrays.stream(myRecords).forEach(r -> jsonArr.put(r.toJSON()));
```

You can then proceed to iterate over your `JSONArray` and then write each contents to the file, if you don't want file to be overwritten; you would need to set append flag to true:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("NewFile.json", true)) {
        file.write(jsonObj.toString());
    }
}
```

You can also write the `JSONArray` directly to file like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
Arrays.stream(myRecords).forEach(r -> jsonArr.put(r.toJSON()));
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("NewFileCompleteArr.json", true)) {
    fileWriter.write(jsonArr.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to close the FileWriter
`file.close()`

Comment: dude read her question. she wanna insert data in json file. or else explain your logic.

Comment: You must close the FileWriter, otherwise it won't flush the current buffer